# Woo Commerce filter

Tags: plugins

I am modifying a job theme and having a problem with woo commerce plugin

There are 3 products to purchase.
1. posting a job (options: 1job, 2 jobs, 5 jobs)
2. Able to read full resumes for 1 day (option: for 1 day, 7 days, 15 days)
3. Both of them (posting jobs and read resumes)

I have successfully done with setting options and making a payment.
But the problem is how I could update these purchase options to user-meta and a custom table.

there is a meta-value called "_Total-amount-jobs" on user-meta. This is for how many jobs he/she can post. like total job amount you can post.
it looks like this _Total-amount-jobs 3 (that means you can post 3 jobs)

there is also a meta-value called "_Resume-expire-day" on user-meta as well. This is for until when he/she is able to read resumes.
the meta-key is date 2013-10-31 17:56:32 (that means you can read resumes by the day)

How can I update user-meta like this after completed payment OR after admin clicks completed button on order list? 
it should be plus (+) for jobs amount. and it should  be new date for resume expire day

I have found a hook for it. on docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/ and "woocommerce_payment_complete" but I am not sure how to update.

This is meta for puchased 5 jobs, 7days on wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta

```
    280 36  _qty    1
    281 36  _tax_class   
    282 36  _product_id 27911
    283 36  _variation_id   28002
    284 36  _line_subtotal  170
    285 36  _line_total 170
    286 36  _line_tax   0
    287 36  _line_subtotal_tax  0
    288 36  pa_job-posting  5-jobs
    289 36  pa_view-resumes view-7-days

    270 35  _qty    1
    271 35  _tax_class   
    272 35  _product_id 27888
    273 35  _variation_id   27961
    274 35  _line_subtotal  300
    275 35  _line_total 300
    276 35  _line_tax   0
    277 35  _line_subtotal_tax  0
    278 35  Posting Amount  1
    279 35  Location    Normal-listing
```

please give me a tip or sample source. 
Thanks

Comment: You are asking a complex question. I would suggest posting the code that you have tried to implement, though even though I couldn't guarantee you'd get a response after that, but at least it won't seem like you are asking for us to do your work for you for free.

Comment: I am sorry to make you feel bad if you did. this work is for my self. not for someone else. I am just trying to find where (or which hook) I should put and how. Thanks again

Comment: I don't feel bad, I'm just saying that if you showed more code/research effort on your part you might elicit more answers. For example, what *isn't* working on the `woocommerce_payment_complete` etc. Either way, the question is borderline off-topic because it is specific to WooCommerce and not WordPress.

Comment: Thanks for ur time and advice. I have found hook. it's woocommerce_order_status_completed. it took really long time for me as wordpress newbie. please understand me :) but i still have problems lol

Comment: Better questions will help get you better answers is all. And your answer might help someone else, so please an answer with a little code in it then. I understand you might not want to reveal everything you're working on, but you can probably post a simplified version. Good luck!

Comment: good I did :) you have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. I have found that this function (woocommerce_order_status_completed) is for when you made a payment or when you give completed status.

```
woocommerce_order_status_completed{
function check_quantity($order_id) {

global $wpdb;

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();

foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_name = $item['name'];
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
    $pa_version = $item['pa_version'];
}    

..... etc...

}
```

I am still looking for how I should get variation values. if you know let know. this is what  I have found.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. I have found that this function (woocommerce_order_status_completed) is for when you made a payment or when you give completed status.

woocommerce_order_status_completed{
function check_quantity($order_id) {

global $wpdb;

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();

foreach ( $items as $item ) {
$product_name = $item['name'];
$product_id = $item['product_id'];
$product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
$pa_version = $item['pa_version'];
}

..... etc...

}
I am still looking for how I should get variation values. if you know let know. this is what I have found. Thanks,